# Reverse proxy example?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering what sort of machine I should get to be a reverse proxy. I've never made one before so I'm sort of confused as to what kind of spec I should look for. So I guess my question is.. how expensive would it be for a machine to forward say.. 50,000 connections a day? What sort of machine should I look for?

Comment: Can I ask what it is you're looking to use a reverse-proxy for? Be it caching/performance or high-availability. Just so I can get an idea if you need anything like layer 7 traffic inspection etc (which will require more CPU than just a simple).

Comment: @Coops I'm using it for high availability / load balancing.

Comment: I've had lots of very good experience with HAProxy (http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). It's actually quite simple to setup once you see a working config file, but yet lets you do some very powerful stuff if you need it (Layer 7 traffic inspection etc). I certainly prefer it over mod_proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50000 connections per day is less than a connection per second in fact. This kind of load is not too high, any average and even below average PC can handle this amount of traffic.

To compare, one of my sites serves about 4,000,000 hits per day using a HP DL360G5 and the reverse proxy shares this hardware with Apache/mod_perl, MySQL and some other stuff.

Comment: Agreed. A low-end PC could easily handle millions of HTTP requests a day in a reverse-proxy-only role. An app I run uses Apache reverse-proxy in front of a Tomcat instance that's doing all the work of the app on the same machine. It's running on a four-year old Dell 1950. Apache never breaks 1-2% CPU with 2-3 million HTTP requests each day.